# ValueError: path is on mount 'D:', start on mount 'C:' while doing pip install

Tags: python, pip

I am new to python, and its ecosystem, so I am having trouble figuring out how to fix an error I am getting while trying to install a library for a project. I understand it has something to due with the fact that my computer has two hard drives, but I do not know how to fix it. (I know putting the project on the other drive probably would, but that drive is too small, and only really has my operating system.)

This is the traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
  status = self.run(options, args)
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 384, in run
  installed = install_given_reqs(
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 53, in install_given_reqs
  requirement.install(
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 910, in install
  self.move_wheel_files(
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 437, in move_wheel_files
  move_wheel_files(
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 458, in move_wheel_files
  clobber(source, dest, False, fixer=fixer, filter=filter)
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 424, in clobber
  record_installed(srcfile, destfile, changed)
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 351, in record_installed
  newpath = normpath(destfile, lib_dir)
File "D:\(name)\(project)\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.8.egg\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 68, in normpath
  return os.path.relpath(src, p).replace(os.path.sep, '/')
File "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ntpath.py", line 703, in relpath
  raise ValueError("path is on mount %r, start on mount %r" % (
ValueError: path is on mount 'D:', start on mount 'C:'
```

Also, further information, though I don't think it is relevant(but just in case), I am installing this package in PyCharm, which itself runs the pip command.

Comment: What command did you have run?

Comment: @Kalana the command was just "pip install pyhf"

Comment: which method did you use to install pyhf. Did you use project interpretor to do this or other method?

Comment: @Kalana I used PyCharm's built in installer, which uses pip.

Comment: When you trying to install any package it automatically done by cmd when you use PyCharm built in installer but the thing is cmd opens always as `C:\Users\User>` but your project is in another local drive **or** your python installation in another local drive. This is mainly drive focused error. There for make sure all installations will be done in one drive.